# How to simplify ABC + A'B'C' into A XNOR B AND B XNOR C

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm currently practicing on Boolean algebra and theorems, recently I found a question that asks to simplify the Boolean expression ABC+A'B'C'. During trying to simplify this when I was trying to construct a KMAP

| A/BC | 00 | 01 | 11 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I realized that I can instead use A XNOR B AND B XNOR C and so I attempted to figure out how to transform it and this is my try:

$$ABC + \overline A \overline B \overline C$$
$$\overline {\overline{(ABC)}  \overline{(\overline A \overline B \overline C)}}$$
$$\overline{(\overline A + \overline B + \overline C)(A + B + C)}$$
$$\overline{\overline AB + \overline AC + \overline BA + \overline BC + \overline CA +\overline CB}$$

after this i can group it up and make the XORS but im stuck and i cannot make the 2 XNOR

Answer (score 0):

These maybe more obvious by K-map:

$$\begin{align*}
\overline AB + \overline AC + \overline BC
&= \overline AB + \overline A\left(B+\overline B\right)C + \overline BC\\
&= \overline AB(1+C) + \overline BC\left(\overline A+1\right)\\
&= \overline AB + \overline BC
\end{align*}$$

Similarly,

$$\overline BA + \overline CA + \overline CB
= \overline BA + \overline CB$$

Then overall,

$$\def\xnor{\mathbin{\text{XNOR}}}
\def\xor{\mathbin{\text{XOR}}}
\begin{align*}
ABC + \overline A \ \overline B \ \overline C
= \cdots 
&= \overline{\overline A B + \overline AC + \overline BA + \overline BC + \overline CA + \overline CB}\\
&= \overline{\overline A B + \overline B A + \overline BC + \overline C B}\\
&= \left(\overline{\overline A B + \overline B A}\right) \left(\overline{\overline BC + \overline C B}\right)\\
&= \left(\overline{A\xor B}\right) \left(\overline{B\xor C}\right)\\
&= (A\xnor  B)(B\xnor C)\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: ahh, I never thought of expanding on 1 to progress with the equation, that really opened my eyes thankyou very much!